# Доступ к элементу в дереве DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть разметка разметка:

```
<ul> 
  <li><img src="1.png"></li> 
  <li><img src="2.png"></li> 
  <li><img src="3.png"></li> 
  <li><img src="4.png"></li> 
  <li><img src="5.png"></li> 
</ul>
```

нужно Нужно переписать строку, удаляющую Li с jQuery

```
$("ul li:first").remove();
```

на На javascript. Я написал

```
var mainObj = document./*getElementsByTagName("ul").*/getElementsByTagName("li")[0]; 
var img = mainObj.firstChild;
mainObj.removeChild(img);
```

Сначала хочу удалить img, а потом li, сразу li не знаю как Сейчас работает, но не всегда. Если раскомментировать, будет ошибка. Нужен полный аналог строки `$("ul li:first").remove();`

Comment: 1 тема - 1 вопрос. Зачем вы полностью изменили содержание вопроса, оставив прежний заголовок?

Comment: сорри. прошлый вопрос решён. не знал, что нельзя

Comment: @olegall, http://jsfiddle.net/FnnED/1/

Comment: есть варианты попроще?

Comment: @olegall, jQuery поэтому и используют (для простоты), а за кулисами все тот же громоздкий нативный javascript. Если вам надо добавить картинку не во все списки на странице, а только в конкретный, то код станет проще: http://jsfiddle.net/UrkQ2/2/, по-другому не знаю. Но избежать как минимум 5ти операций у вас не получится:

  1. Создать img
  2. Присвоить путь до картинки
  3. Создать li
  4. Добавить img в li
  5. Добавить li в конец ul

Comment: @olegall jQuery это и есть js. зачем вообще что-то переписывать ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var mainObj = document./*getElementsByTagName("ul").*/getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
mainObj.parentNode.removeChild(mainObj);
```